# Implementing ImageJ macro commands into an existing Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, imagej

I'm trying to change the existing plugin [OpenComet](http://opencomet.org/) for ImageJ. I'm not into Java, so perhaps it's an easy task.

What I'm trying to implement are the following things

1. `run("Bio-Formats Windowless Importer", "open=path autoscale color_mode=Default  view=Hyperstack stack_order=XYCZT");`
   opening my files with the help of the Bioformat Importer plugin
2. `run("Flip Horizontally");`

This is supposed to be placed into the following code:

```
// Iterate over each input file
            for(int i=0;i<inFiles.length;i++){
                // Try to open file as image
//NUMBER 1 BIOFORMAT IMPORT AT THIS POINT               
                ImagePlus imp = IJ.openImage(inFiles[i].getPath());
                                // If image could be opened, run comet analysis
                if(imp!=null){
//NUMBER 2 FLIPPING AT THIS POINT
                    String imageKey =  inFiles[i].getName();
```

Moreover I would need to import the class of the BioFormat Importer or something like this. Wouldn't I?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. `run("Bio-Formats Windowless Importer", "open=path autoscale
>      color_mode=Default  view=Hyperstack stack_order=XYCZT");`
>
>    opening my files with the help of the Bioformat Importer plugin

You can achieve this using the `BF` helper class of bio-formats (see its [API documentation](http://javadoc.imagej.net/Bio-Formats/index.html?loci/plugins/BF.html)). For a javascript example, have a look [here](http://fiji.sc/Scripting_toolbox#Opening_an_image_using_Bio-Formats). In Java, this could look like:

```
import loci.plugins.BF;
  [...]
ImagePlus[] imps = BF.openImagePlus(inFiles[i].getPath());
ImagePlus imp = imps[0];
```

> 2. `run("Flip Horizontally");`

Use the [recorder](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-31.html#sub:Record...) (*Plugins > Macros > Record...*) in *Java* mode to get the required command:

```
import ij.IJ;
 [...]
IJ.run(imp, "Flip Horizontally", "");
```

If you want to know the Java command at a lower level, use the [Command Finder](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-31.html#sub:Command-Finder) (press [L] or *Plugins > Utilities > Find Commands...*) and type "flip" and you'll find the class that implements the command:

```
ij.plugin.filter.Transformer("fliph")
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the long explanation, but still I cannot open the files. It's not working.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on _how_ it is "not working"? For example by providing a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the error message(s) you get?

Comment: Sry, but there was nothing to elaborate...just nothing happened. But now like this it works, I don't know if it makes sense...:    'importClass(Packages.loci.plugins.BF);
 
 var imps = BF.openImagePlus(path);

 ImagePlus imp = BF.openImagePlus(inFiles[i].getPath());
 imps[0].show();'
But flipping does not work at all,just nothing happens the command is completely ignored

Comment: Careful, you are mixing Java and Javascript here. What is the content of `inFiles[i].getPath()`?